# How to implement queue in a nodejs cli app?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do something and I am not finding the way.
I have a cli app in nodeJS.
This application must run, and in its execution my intention is that it can launch some processes (in a queue), but not wait for the response of said processes.

I have tried it with bee-queue but when I do the main app (cli app), it is frozen, and it never finishes its execution.

Is there a way to get it with bee-queue?

In summary what I need is:

- Run a nodeJS cli app
- The cli app runs and queues a number of processes
- The cli app terminates (and the processes continue to do their work)

Comment: You would obviously require some sort of background process to process the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module instead of a queue.

This way you'll be able to run the processes in the background and you'll also have the ability to control or handle the responses from the processes.

[This](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/) is a nice summery of the usage

Comment: Thanks, I had taken it into account, but I need to limit the number of processes that I want to execute simultaneously and be able to queue them since the worker consumes a lot of CPU.

Comment: Then I think that you'll need another process for the queue handling.. RabbitMq is a good tool for that. By using RabbitMq (or any other pub/sub process) you'll have full control over the queue.